# Why the extra "בֶן" in חֲנַנְיָה's name?

Tags: talmud-gemara, names, maseches-shabbos, maseches-menachos

The Mishna in [Shabbos](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shabbat.1.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (1:4) references חֲנַנְיָה בֶן חִזְקִיָּה בֶן גֻּרְיוֹן, with two בֶן's, but when referenced in [Menachos](http://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.45a?lang=he) (45a):

> אמר רב זכור אותו האיש לטוב **וחנינא בן חזקיה** שמו

the Tanna's name no longer has the second בֶן גֻּרְיוֹן. Is there a reason why in the Mishna Shabbos (1:4) חֲנַנְיָה בֶן חִזְקִיָּה also extends back to בֶן גֻּרְיוֹן?

Comment: It would appear to be name of the grandfather as well.

Comment: That's what I assumed as well,but thought it was peculiar the Mishna included his grandfather while the gemara didn't.

Comment: It might be the style of the gemara (Shabbos 13b) as opposed to the mishna or the specific identification may be because in the time of the mishna someone else was around, while in the time of the gemara the other person was not remembered.